# Why we used present perfect here

Tags: present-perfect, present-perfect-progressive

What kind of feeling we give readers when we use present perfect continuous with present perfect.

> We have been waiting for Nancy for the last two hours, but she still hasn't arrived.

the writter use "she still hasn't arrived" in present perfect to show that she didn't come and this action of her is ongoing until this moment that we are waiting; right? or is there another reason to use this tense that way.

I want to know when we use present perfect continuous with present perfect and what do we want to emphasize, when we use it that way.

Comment: Note that when Colin said *please ask those supplementary questions as separate questions in ELL*, he specifically said ***with examples of what you are asking about.*** But the example here is ***the same*** as the one you gave before, so I don't understand how this can be a "different" question.

Comment: ...repeating the present perfect continuous would give *We have been waiting for Nancy for the last two hours, but she still **hasn't been arriving***, which is nonsense. As Colin pointed out when answering your earlier question, ***Arrive is a point event:** it is very rare to use it in a continuous construction.* Where obviously *to **wait,** to be **waiting*** refer to actions that *by definition* take time (they're not "instant, point events").

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/126/fumblefingers I asked this question in my previous question and they recommend me to ask another question in this site, I think they did get my question back then so l change my question to be more close to the problem that lm' facing right now, and another reason is that l could find any other similar sentence with this two tense together so l use the same one again

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/126/fumblefingers I didn't ask about why we didn't use present perfect continuous in both sentence, right now, I just asking what kind of feeling some one gets when we use present perfect continuous and present perfect together and when we use it that way, because l don't have any other similar sentence with these two tense together, l use the same sentence that I used in previous question.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "what kind of feeling", unless you are asking about what feeling the speaker might have: it suggests that speaker is frustrated or impatient. The sentence above is completely normal and unexceptionable to me.

Comment: @fatemehkhayat: By definition, ***wait*** refers to an "extended" action. Where the perfect continuous ***have been waiting*** implies that lengthy process *is still ongoing* (as opposed to *We **waited*** or ***...were waiting***, both of which imply speaker has *stopped* waiting). That "continuing to wait" aspect, and the intensified usage ***still** hasn't arrived* are strong indicators that the speaker is annoyed, as Colin says.